# Selecting by attributes in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, fields-attributes, select, arcgis-10.6

[image]

Using ArcMap 10.6 I am trying to 'select by attribute' data that is separated by a comma.

For example: `passive, football, soccer` or `passive, playground` and so on
with the objective to calculate the number of each activity.

I don't use Python script.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a bit more information about your data - the field or fields you are trying to select, and the data in them.  A screenshot may be useful as well.

Comment: For reference, the problem you are encountering is the reason that lists are poor practice in database design. Best practice uses a one-to-many relationship, with each facility-activity being a separate row. Wildcard searches on lists are hyper-inefficient, while joins are the reason databases were created.

Comment: Are you trying to select just `soccer` and then in another selection just `cycling` etc.?

Comment: Are all of your activities in the same order? For example, will there ever be a `passive, soccer` and a `soccer, passive`? My first thought would be to create an attribute for each activity with just a true/false value.

Comment: I am trying to select each activity individually to enable a count to be collated. Unfortunately the list is not in any particular order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a small script to avoid repeating multiple selections :

```
import arcpy

## set the names of variables
fc = r'your_feature_class.shp'
fieldName = 'yourfield'

## initialize a dictionnary to store all values
dictionnary = {}
## loop on all features
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [fieldName]) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        for dictKey in [x.strip() for x in row[0].split(",")]: #loop on all the values separated with "," and remove the blank spaces on both sides
            if dictKey in dictionnary:
                dictionnary[dictKey]+=1
            else:
                dictionnary[dictKey]=1   
print(dictionnary)
```

Comment: +1 Why do you use an UpdateCursor instead of SearchCursor?

Comment: @Midavalo  because I was distracted ! thanks for spotting it

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this in the Select by Attributes dialog:

```
Activity_l LIKE '%netball%'
```

This will select all records that contain the word `netball` anywhere in the `Activity_l` field.  For another activity replace `netball` with another such as `Activity_l LIKE '%cricket%'`

Comment: Will this type of count/selection be required in the future? May be a good opportunity to Add attribute fields and use Field Calculator to permanently make this part of the table, per @Fezter's suggestion above.

Answer (score 0):

A twisted (experimental) answer by using Field Calculator:

Field Name:

ANY FIELD WILL WORK (see notes)

Expression:

`Raise_At_The_End( !Activity_l! )`

Expression Type:

`PYTHON_9.3`

Code Block:

```
total_records = 10 #Assume there are 10 records
count = 1
a_list = []

def Raise_At_The_End(rec):
    global total_records, count, a_list
    if count != total_records-1:
        a_list += map(unicode.strip, rec.split(','))
        count += 1
    else:
        from collections import Counter
        tabular = '\r\\n'.join(["{}\t{}".format(*j)  for j in sorted(Counter(a_list).items())])
        raise Exception, tabular
```

Notes:

- The expected result is to get a **"Geoprocessing error message"** but there is a  trick here (twisted part). This is intentional to end processing by raising an exception and writing the result message. The result also appears in the geoprocessing tool's Result window (in ArcMap, **Geoprocessing menu > Results**), under Messages.
- `total_records` should be equal to the number of records to be processed (which can be seen from Attribute Table). Any selection is honoured as usual.
- Any field in the table can be used since the script does not update any table rows